# Salesforce PHP Toolkit 20 Error: SoapClient::__setSoapHeaders(): Invalid SOAP header

Tags: php, soap, salesforce

I am trying to do a very simple integration with the Salesforce PHP Toolkit 20.0. Everything works fine on my local server so I think it must be a server setting, but I don't see any issues with my server configuration. Additionally, the errors I'm getting aren't helping at all.

I've removed the actual authentication piece because I'm getting errors just running the basic createConnection function. Here is the code:

```
define("SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR", "soapclient");
require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforceEnterpriseClient.php');

try {
    $mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
    $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/enterprise.wsdl.xml');
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
    exit($e->faultstring);
}
```

Running that code alone, I get the following error:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  SoapClient::__setSoapHeaders(): Invalid SOAP header in <b>/home/website/public_html/app/equity/soapclient/SforceBaseClient.php</b> on line <b>325</b><br />
```

My server is running PHP 5.6 and OpenSSL, SOAP, SSL, and cURL is enabled.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea why, but changing my Salesforce password fixed the issue.